# IIS and Yii2 pretty URL

Tags: .htaccess, iis, web-config, yii2

What is the `.htaccess` equivalent for IIS to enable pretty URLs in Yii2 on IIS. Indeed, I don't know what could I do with `web.conf` to allow those URLs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this on your web.config and save it on the root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>

<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Hide Yii Index" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
              ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" 
              ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule> 
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This one is working perfectly for the frontend . But not for the backend and when I add a web.config file to the backend web directory it conflicts with the frontend one causing Rewrite Module error.  Any help ?

Comment: @XXLend You have to host each of frontend and backend in two different hosts or websites. i.e `mydomain.com` for frontend and `sub.mydomain.com` for backend.